# AppInsights instrumentation key is replaced when win universal app is published to Windows Store

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, azure-application-insights

I have a simple Windows Univeral Application with Azure Application Insights enabled in it. First published version worked well - all telemetry data was visible in AppInsights dashboard. But after I updated the app, strange thing happened - no telemetry data is generated at all.

After installing the version of the application from Windows Store, and tracing web requests with Fiddler, I've found out VERY strange thing - instrumentation key (iKey) sent in AppInsights requests is UNKNOWN for me. I mean that this is not a one of my AppInsights instances!

On the other hand, when I sideload the same package I've used for publish, than correct (expected) iKey is used in traced web requests.

This makes me think that my iKey is somehow replaced in published version of application. **How is this possible?**

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** AppInsights initialization code is the following (in App class):

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    var instrumentationKey =
#if DEBUG
    Current.Resources["ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey.Debug"].ToString();
#else
    Current.Resources["ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey.Release"].ToString();
#endif
    Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(instrumentationKey);

    // ...
}
```

And one more time - this worked well in first version of the application and was broken only after update (wich did not touch any AppInsights related stuff).

**UPDATE (2016-03-21):** Following recommendations in the answers, I've done the following:

1. Moved release iKey into ApplicationInsights.config file
2. Changed initialization logic to replace the iKey only in case of Debug mode:

   ```
   protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
   {
   #if DEBUG
       var instrumentationKey = Current.Resources["ApplicationInsights.InstrumentationKey.Debug"].ToString();
       await Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync(instrumentationKey);
   #else
       await Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync()
   #endif

       // ...
   }
   ```
3. Republished the application to Windows Store.

Now AppInsights is working correctly - my iKey is used in AppInsights web requests and data appears in admin panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you have an applicationinsights.config file in your project?

if you do not, I *believe* the store will create one for you so that the reports work, because it doesn't know you're setting the key in code. you might want to add an applicationinsights.config file, and put in one of your ikeys, even if you are then setting the key explicitly in code.

Comment: Yes, I have the ApplicationInsights.config file, but it does not contain any iKeys - it is set only in code.
This worked well in the first published version of the application. Is it possible Microsoft changed this behavior recently?
So, should I try to add my debug iKey into the ApplicationInsights.config, and leave the same logic in code to substitute it at runtime?
Seems strange to me.
And even more strange - where the iKey substituted by Windows Store is taken from? May I see this AppInsights instance somewhere in the Azure/WindowsStore admin panel?

Comment: what's odd is that since you're explicitly calling that version of initializeasync with that key explicitly, it should only be getting the key from there.  Are you sure there's no other call to initializeasync anywhere else (app.xaml.cs?) that is setting it to the store's key first?  

The key generated by the store is created in their internal area, only for powering the devcenter dashboard, so I don't think you can see it anywhere but in the devcenter.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I don't have any other initialization calls. Finally, I've created the ApplicationInsights.config file with release iKey and it helped - see **UPDATE (2016-03-21)** section in my question. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 1):

The ApplicationInsights SDK for Store apps, only works with ApplicationInsights.config.

The Store looks for this file, and if no instrumentation key is set, it injects one.

The SDK on the other hand, will always respect instrumentation key coming from the configuration file.